# Adding a lambda function as hook in use-package

Tags: hooks, use-package

I'm trying to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684738/how-do-i-set-emacs-tab-size-to-4-chars-wide-for-py-files) answer to use-package elegantly. It requires that I  hook a lambda function to python-mode. I came up with this solution — which works:

```lisp
(use-package python
 :hook
  (python-mode . (lambda ()
                   (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
                   (setq tab-width 4)
                   (setq python-indent-offset 4))))
```

but I find it inelegant, as it requires me to repeat "python-mode" inside the use-package for python (shouldn't that be obvious?). Is there a better way, and if not, why? I'm not sure I understand well the hook process in use-package.

Comment: Hook is to add something for this package on another module load hook, like `prog-mode` would be. That's why you need to give its name first. In this case why not just place those variables in `:config`?

Comment: See [Hooks in use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks).

Comment: @Muihlinn Thank you for this clarification. So using a hook on a package is exactly the same as putting the hook function inside `:config` ?
I reread your first sentence 5 times and still find it a little cryptic. It means that in use-package, `:hook` is used to load a package that the current package would need if a different third package were loaded, is that it?

Comment: No, I meant that you've set up a hook which will load after configuring that very same package to simply set a few variables. Just put those variables in :config and save a call.

Comment: In this case, `indent-tabs-mode` and `tab-width` are buffer-local variables, and since they potentially have optimal values that differ depending on the major mode you're in, they should NOT be moved inside `:config` as suggested (unless you always want to have that as default, for all major modes). You might move `python-indent-offset` though. `:config` has code that is evaluated *after* the major mode is loaded (usually once), and the functions you add to the hook are called every time a new buffer triggers that major mode.

Comment: Your question seems to be "shouldn't it be obvious that if I'm configuring a package called `X` and I want to add to a hook, that the hook name would be `X-mode-hook`?".  The answer is no, it's not *obvious*.  It might well be a common case, but it's absolutely not a given.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially the simplification of defaulting to `<modename>-mode-hook`, for a given `<modename>`, could have been implemented in `use-package`, yes, since it is in the [Major Mode Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html#Major-Mode-Conventions). However, it seems the authors decided to use this notation to simplify adding the current package (the package in the current use-package declaration) to another hook; see [[here](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks)]. Also, notice that hooks may be used for several other reasons than to start major modes, so their name may vary a lot.